# What is the speed of a kugelblitz black hole?

Tags: black-holes, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, speed

Would a [kugelblitz black hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelblitz_(astrophysics)) travel at the speed of light? Would it slow down after swallowing more mass?

Answer (score 4):

For the photons to interact to create a kugelblitz black hole, they would have to be traveling in different directions, and the resultant average velocity would be less than $c$ in any one direction.

Comment: 1. Does this limitation come from plancks temperature? If yes, then is this a hard limitation or do we simply enter a grey area of physis because we don't understand quantum gravitation?

Comment: 2. If the limitation comes from plancks temperature, there is no way to have 3 or more photons in a point to have velocity c. Ie., 3 photons with same frequency/energy, and directions (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,-1,0) would have a velocity of 1/3 c in direction (1,0,0), after forming a black hole. This is true for all possible combinations. This is what your conclusion is based on right? If so then I understand it, thanks for the answer.